# Get the mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get a mysql data from the table, here -

```
try
    {
        $stmt = $user->prepare("SELECT status FROM users");
        $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result['status'] != "Y")
        {
            $error[] = "Some error warning!";
        }
        else 
        {
            // Some php codes
        }
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here user is a class where prepare is db connection mysql prepare function. The error always prints - "Array!". I am new to php. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I have managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello, you have no output function (Where come from the "Array" ?). So, you need to improve your post with more code. We can't help you without provide us the way you display the result :)
Advice: Here, you make a query that will return all data (several lines). With your fetch function you take only the first line. SO on your SQL command add a `LIMIT 1` instruction or add some `WHERE` conditions to limit the result or using a loop (foreach) to iterate on each objects.

Comment: I have just echoed the output inside a span. It doesn't seems like echoing error has any problem. Because all others are working fine, accept this equality comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the call of `PDOStatement::execute()`. See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for some examples.

Have you already tried this?

```
try
{
    $stmt = $user->prepare("SELECT status FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result['status'] != "Y")
    {
        $error[] = "Some error warning!";
    }
    else 
    {
        // Some php codes
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Regarding the `Array!` output: Did you post the whole code of your script? Were do you try to print the array `$error`?

Comment: You're right, but you left in some syntax problems. `$sth` != `$stmt`